# Reading GML data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, xml, gml, citygml

Is there a specific reason, why QGIS can display some CityGML data from the Bavarian surveying agency right out of the box and other XML or GML files from that same source do not show anything?

When using the test datasets (https://www.ldbv.bayern.de/service/testdaten.html), the LoD1 data can be imported to QGIS by default and buildings are also on the correct spots.

[image]

The `ogrinfo` output for the working LoD1 data:

```
ERROR 1: Cannot import urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32*DE_DHHN2016_NH due to ALLOW_FILE_ACCESS=NO
INFO: Open of `C:/xxx/xxx/xxx/Testdaten_LoD1_CityGML/714_5324.xml'
      using driver `GML' successful.
Metadata:
  NAME=LoD1_714_5324_1_BY

Layer name: Building
Geometry: 3D PolyhedralSurface
Feature Count: 83
Extent: (714138.984000, 5323992.891000) - (714985.320000, 5324329.628000)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
Geometry Column = lod1Solid
gml_id: String (0.0) NOT NULL
name: String (19.0)
creationDate: String (10.0)
informationSystem: String (66.0)
externalReference|externalObject|name: String (16.0)
Grundrissaktualitaet: String (10.0)
HoeheLoD1: Real (0.0)
Gemeindeschluessel: Integer (0.0)
DatenquelleDachhoehe: Integer (0.0)
DatenquelleLage: Integer (0.0)
DatenquelleBodenhoehe: Integer (0.0)
BezugspunktDach: Integer (0.0)
HoeheGrund: Real (0.0)
HoeheDach: Real (0.0)
Methode: Integer (0.0)
NiedrigsteTraufeDesGebaeudes: Real (0.0)
Geometrietyp2DReferenz: Integer (0.0)
function: String (10.0)
measuredHeight: Real (0.0)
measuredHeight_uom: String (13.0)
storeysAboveGround: Integer (0.0)
CountryName: String (7.0)
LocalityName: String (7.0)
ThoroughfareName: String (21.0)
```

The same procedure with the LoD2 data (which are now released for open access of total Bavaria) results in an empty canvas.

[image]

Here the `ogrinfo` output for the not working LoD2 data.

```
ERROR 1: Cannot import urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32*DE_DHHN2016_NH due to ALLOW_FILE_ACCESS=NO
INFO: Open of `C:/xxx/xxx/xxx/Testdaten_LoD2_UTM32_citygml/714_5324.xml'
      using driver `GML' successful.
Metadata:
  NAME=LoD2_714_5324_1_BY

Layer name: Building
Geometry: PolyhedralSurface
Feature Count: 84
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
Geometry Column = lod2Solid
gml_id: String (0.0) NOT NULL
name: String (18.0)
creationDate: String (10.0)
informationSystem: String (66.0)
externalReference|externalObject|name: String (16.0)
StandLK: String (10.0)
Gemeindeschluessel: Integer (0.0)
DatenquelleDachhoehe: Integer (0.0)
DatenquelleLage: Integer (0.0)
DatenquelleBodenhoehe: Integer (0.0)
HoeheGrund: Real (0.0)
HoeheDach: Real (0.0)
NiedrigsteTraufeDesGebaeudes: Real (0.0)
Methode: Integer (0.0)
function: String (10.0)
roofType: Integer (0.0)
measuredHeight: Real (0.0)
measuredHeight_uom: String (13.0)
CountryName: String (7.0)
LocalityName: String (7.0)
ThoroughfareName: String (24.0)
```

The attribute table is present for both data sets.

Comment: projection? complexity? - please show us some information about the data sets that do and don't work - maybe `ogrinfo` output?

Comment: which dataset in https://www.ldbv.bayern.de/service/testdaten.html is the Lod1 GML data?

Comment: the working LoD1 GML data is the first entry: https://www.geodaten.bayern.de/oadownload/Testdaten/LoD1_abgeleitet_CityGML.zip

Comment: @IanTurton the projection should be UTM32 (EPSG: 25832)  for both.

Comment: Never assume, please show that you have checked

Comment: ;) of course, yes. The meta data state the UTM32 for both data sets. And the picture with the LoD1 here shows the correct position with UTM32. By the way, this is the official projection for bavarian official data and data from that source is only shipped with that particular projection.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is an OGR problem that should be fixed with version 3.7.0:
[CityGML Import not working with LoD2 files](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/51647)